# How to draw three arrays into one cdf graph in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, cdf

I have a matrix like this

a =

```
1.2000    1.5000    1.1000
1.4000    1.9000    1.3000
1.6000    1.8000    1.7000
```

I want to draw a cdf graph which these three columns shared in one y-axis in Matlab.

Can anyone help me with this? Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just use `cumsum` to compute the matrix of accumulated sums columnwise.

```
b = cumsum(a)

b = 
    1.2000  1.500  1.100
    2.6000  3.400  2.400
    4.2000  5.200  4.100
```

Then call `plot` which will plot each column in a separate line.

```
plot(b, '-.');
```